# use of XMPP in flex code on UDP Protocol

Tags: c++, apache-flex, xmpp

I am working private network.This alread developped product which implemented using TCP(client server technology).

**Existing product is as follows**

1. There is a UI which is developed using flex, where user can  see video or snapshot
2. There is a server which is developed using c++,which redirects request from UI to gateway.
3. There is gateway which is connected with the Camera,which stream video to UI through server.

Now we wanted to add p2p technology to existing client server.So it will support TCP as Well As UDP.
Presently we are exploring flex and XMPP to implement the p2p.

as newer version flex  of flex support p2p using RTMFP, but thats the propriety protocol of adobe.if we use RTMFP we need to change all the existing code that we dont want

I wanted to implemented to p2p using flex client(UI) which will use XMPP  to communicate with Gateway and Server.

**So the question is**

1. Is it possible to use XMPP from flex code
2. Will XMPP support UDP p2p or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. You can use the [as3xmpp](http://code.google.com/p/as3xmpp/) library to communicate to servers using that protocol.
2. To my knowledge, no. My understanding is that the network protocol used in p2p connections is internalized, and doesn't allow for public APIs to define their own network protocol (unlike Sockets for example).